# Parse JSON response into an array

Tags: c#, json

I am unable to convert or deserialize the below json response in to an array, i need to store attribute content in to an array using c#

the below is my json response format

```
{
  "doc1.doc": {
    "category": "word",
    "name": "doc1.doc",
    "size": "10 mb",
    "content": [
      "name",
      "age",
      "dob"
    ]
  }
}
```

my c# code

```
var deser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);
            Console.WriteLine(deser.doc1.doc.content);
```

i'm receiving my response using rest sharp

Comment: well, you're not *trying* to deserialising it to an array - but to `dynamic`.

Comment: Just convert it as such. `var myarray = deser.doc1.doc.content as List<string>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are going to have is that your response has "doc1.doc" as an object name which has a dot in the middle.  In C# you separate out the different parts of a dynamic by using a dot.  So although can you deserialise it OK, you run into problems when trying to access parts directly as a dynamic as the compiler believes that doc1.doc are two separate parts and then at runtime you have an issue.

So you need to access your data in a different way by using the field name.  This should work

```
var content = deser["doc1.doc"].content;
```

Or if you want an array

```
string[] content = deser["doc1.doc"].content.ToObject<string[]>();
```